# How to get Emacs to automatically open a specific directory on startup?

Tags: customize, start-up, directory

I would like Emacs to open the folder `$HOME/Documents/CodeLite/CPP-Math-Projects/Simple-Pendulum` on startup and show it in the directory browser. Is there a way to do this? I have read https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Startup-Summary.html, but it is too abstract for me to follow, given the fact I am fairly unconfident with Emacs Lisp.

Answer (score 3):

Oops, never mind, I read the link I provided earlier again and I finally got how to turn it into an `~/.emacs` modification. Specifically I added:

```
(setq initial-buffer-choice "~/Documents/CodeLite/CPP-Math-Projects/Simple-Pendulum")
```

to my `~/.emacs` file.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on MS Windows, consider using this simple way:

Create a Windows shortcut, with:

- `runemacs.exe` (with its path), in field *Target*.  Include any command-line switches you like - e.g., `D:\Emacs-25.1\bin\runemacs.exe --debug-init`
- The directory you want Emacs to start in, in field *Start in*.

You can also have Emacs start out by visiting that directory in Dired. To do that, just add the directory at the end of field *Target*.

Then, to start Emacs, just double-click your shortcut.

Comment: Na, I use Linux and only Linux. But I know how to create a desktop config file to open emacs to whichever folder I want. I just prefer a config file adjustment.

Answer (score 1):

To open a directory at startup you can also insert (find-file "/path/to/dir") in init.el